# NameError: name 'C' is not defined` error Converting Temperature

Tags: python, if-statement, nameerror

I'm working on this Python code to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and the second code that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit. I wrote each code the same way, using (if/else) but whenever I try to make the first condition true. For example, when temperature F = -400 I get a `NameError: name 'C' is not defined` error.

I tried changed the line position for C so it runs before the last print line. But still no luck. The second code part that converts C to F runs without this error. I tried putting the equation for C after the last print line but still the same error.

Is this something that I may be missing on the first part that may be preventing me from making the first condition true?

I'm running Python 2.7.10 and using  Terminal on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11)

**Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius:**

```
F = int(raw_input("Enter Temperature In Fahrenheit:")) 

if F >= (-459.67):

    print "Temperature in absolute zero cannot be achieved"

else: 

    C = F - 32 * (0.555556) 
print "The temperature is %.1f" 'C'  % C
```

**Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:**

```
C = int(raw_input("Enter Temperature In Celsius:"))

if C <= (-273.15):   

    print "Temperature in absolute zero cannot be achieved" 

else:                                                        

    print "The temperature is %.1f" 'F' % F                 
F = C * (1.8) + 32
```

Comment: `if F >= -459.67` then `C` is not defined.

Comment: You could raise an error when bad input is given. For example: `raise ValueError("Temperature in absolute zero cannot be achieved"")`.

Comment: Note that 1/ you're converting to an integer `F = int(...`, yet you compare with floating point values in the next line, and 2/ you compare whether the Fahrenheit value is *above* -459.67 to deem the input value to be incorrect (but you do this correct when comparing `C <= -273.15`. (And no, you don't need parentheses around those float values. I don't know why you think that.)

Comment: neither of the code segments make any sense, the first tells the user that `temperature in absolute zero cannot be achieved` for a temperature **greater then -459.67** and the second one defines F after trying to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people said, there are many errors. One solution is:

```
F = float(raw_input("Enter Temperature In Fahrenheit:"))
if F <= (-459.67):
    print "Temperature in absolute zero cannot be achieved"
else:
    C = F - 32 * (0.555556)
    print "The temperature is %.1f" 'C'  % C

# ----------------------------------------------------------

C = float(raw_input("Enter Temperature In Celsius:"))
if C <= (-273.15):
    print "Temperature in absolute zero cannot be achieved"
else:
    F = C * (1.8) + 32
    print "The temperature is %.1f" 'F' % F
```

Comment: Thank you! replacing float with int helped. I also added C variable after F and I'm no longer seeing the error.